Temporarily modify logging format in a python library (unknown logging context)
I am writing a python library which needs to log already-formatted strings at some point. I'd like to do something like:

store the current logging config
replace all formatters by a basic %(message)s formatter
log the strings
restore the logging config

All the examples I've found regarding custom Formatters/Handlers in the logging module assume we can specify the full logging setup because we actually implement and run an application. Here, I implement a library which could be used in various contexts and I don't know what kind of handlers will be setup.
From the logging module documentation, I don't see how to retrieve an exhaustive list of handlers and get their current formatters.
I use Python 3.9.
To provide more specific context, I call an external software (written in Matlab) that comes with its own log system. I collect those logs through stdout and want to append them to the python logs, to have a unified output. The Matlab logs are already formatted, explaining why I just want to pass them verbatim to the python log system.

Why can the strings not be logged without modifying the logging format?

What is the usecase. Context seems quite ambiguous. Can you provide a use case perhaps in code and what you expect the output to be.

@mkrieger1 I've added some context. Thanks

I recommend using structlog library, it's much more advanced than logging lib

You've perhaps still not provided enough information about the interaction between your Python program and the external app, but if you run the external app and collect its output, you could just add it to the log like this:
import logging, subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('ls -l'.split())  # example of external program
output = output.decode('utf-8')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Output from external app follows:\n%s', output)

If you run this code, you'll see output like this:
DEBUG:root:Output from external app follows:
total 128
drwxr-xr-x 1 runner runner  118 Jun 19  2023 76504696
drwxr-xr-x 1 runner runner   98 Aug 15  2023 76893030
drwxr-xr-x 1 runner runner  108 Sep  6  2023 77042978

Of course your ls results will differ, but you can see that the output of ls -l is appended to the log without any special formatting. I've just used very basic logging configuration to illustrate what I mean.

Thanks for your answer! I was also going for the newline solution as a simple alternative. The only issue is if I want to collect the output and log it as the subprocess runs. In that case, there might be many auxiliary "output from subprocess:" cluttering the logs, but it might be tolerable.
